# convertion/Flattening of Some(Array(Array(Array(String)))) to Array(String)

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I have an `Option[Array[Array[Array[String]]]]` and I want to convert to it `Array[String]` or Atleast `Some(Array[String])`.

I have tried with `.flatten` method.

I can print using `.map(_.map(_.map(_.foreach(print))))` but want to store this printed thing as List.

Expectation: `Array[String]` or `Some(Array(String))`.

Comment: In order to provide a [mcve] it's better to also add an example of a data set you are trying to convert.

Comment: Please format your code when asking your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly the Structure you can do:

For `Option[Array[String]]`

```
myArray.map(_.flatten.flatten)
```

For `Array[String]`:

```
myArray.toArray.flatten.flatten.flatten
```

Comment: I added also a version for `Array[String]`

Answer (score 2):

To convert `Option[Array[Array[Array[String]]]]` to `Option[Array[String]]` do this:

```
.map(_.flatten.flatten)
```

To print the data inside the result, do this

```
.foreach(_.foreach(println))
```